# accessing json object in php

Tags: php, json

How can I access `AirportCode` of `Origin` from the code below.Please Explain with foreach  looping.

```json
"Search": {
  "FlightDataList": {
    "JourneyList": [
      [
        {
          "FlightDetails": {
            "Details": [
              [
                {
                  "Origin": {
                    "AirportCode": "DEL",
                    "CityName": "Delhi",
                    "AirportName": "Delhi",
                    "DateTime": "2020-10-25 11:40:00"
                  },
                  "Destination": {
                     "AirportCode": "BOM",
                     "CityName": "Mumbai",
                     "AirportName": "Mumbai",
                     "DateTime": "2020-10-25 14:00:00"
                   }
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
                 "Price": {
                            "Currency": "INR",
                            "TotalDisplayFare": 4480,
                            "PriceBreakup": {
                                "BasicFare": 3870,
                                "Tax": 610,
                                "AgentCommission": 0,
                                "AgentTdsOnCommision": 0
                            }
                      }
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

*I have attached my code. This code repeatedly shows AirportCode but I need only once*

```
    <?php
$obj= json_decode($json);
    foreach($obj->Search->FlightDataList as $fdl){
      foreach($fdl as $l1){
        foreach($l1 as $l2){
          foreach($l2->FlightDetails->Details as $l3){
            foreach($l3 as $l4){
              foreach ($l4 as $l5) {
               
               echo $l5->AirportCode ?? '';
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: But this is a JavaScript object? What has PHP to do with it?

Comment: `Search.FlightDataList.JourneyList[0][0].FlightDetails.Details[0][0].Origin.AirportCode`

Comment: Can you please explain how to code in php

Comment: How to use for each looping in this code

Comment: Where's the code you are talking about? The question contains only some kind of object, which isn't even valid JSON

Comment: As you've added some PHP code: what do you mean by "not working"? What have you tried to debug **why** this is not working?

Comment: I have compiled this code but it repeatedly shows the Airportcode but i need only once

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php will help.

Comment: I have used but not working.Thanks for your help.